# Is there a formula to calculate EVs?

Tags: pokemon-series

I was looking on Google if there is a formula to know which are the EV that has a Pokémon but i only found calculator that needs that values to get the IV, but that's not what I want.

I found the formula to calculate the IV but i would like to know if exists one for EV.

Edit: I edit to add more details.

I asked this question because i was intrigued to know how it works. I was playing Pokémon Red Fire and the idea came to my head. I was looking on Google for my question and i found formulas to calculate the stats, and the stats needs the EV and IV and i thought that maybe exists a formula to calculate the EV.

For example, if i have a Charizard lvl 50 get the EV from his stats, but as i read it's not possible because it needs to know which Pokémon i defeated with Charizard

Comment: How would it be possible to do this?  You do know what EVs are and how they are calculated, right?

Comment: Technically, I think, you could calculate EVs if you knew IVs, but if you're playing a 6th gen pokemon game, the Super Training app shows your EVs as an octagon.

Comment: @Chippies I'm not playing the last gen...so if i want to calculate EV i need to know the IVs and if i don't know the IVs i can't calculate the EVs...

Comment: You should indicate which version of the game you are playing. Without that information, it's not possible to give an accurate answer.

Comment: @Chippies Actually it's an hexagon, not an octagon :)

Comment: @pinckerman you are right, I was thinking hexagon, but since I didn't actually check at the time, I somehow thought there were a bit more stats than 6, so hexagon couldn't be it :P But yeah, it is a hexagon, my bad.

Comment: @alejandro-bar - There isn't a formula to calculate them per-se, but depending on the game you're playing it can be calculated using tricks in-game. You're not playing the latest generation, you've mentioned that already, but specifically which generation/game are you playing?

Answer (score 7):

In Generation 6, go on Super Training and get yourself a reset bag - It's the pure white one. You can get them by continuously tapping the default punching bag on the main Super Training screen.

Once you have a reset bag **SAVE YOUR GAME** and have your Pokemon punch the reset bag. The bag activates, your EV's are reduced to zero and the amount of EV's lost in each category will pop-up. It will not be there long so make sure to write them down.

Now you can reset your game and your EV's will be back to normal before the reset bag.

*This method works on both Pokemon X and Y as well as Pokemon Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire.*

Answer (score 6):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Statistic#Determination_of_stats), from Generation 3 onward, Pokemon use these formulas to determine stats at each level:

[image: HP formula: HP = [2*B + IV + (EV/4)]*[L/100] + L + 10]

[image: other stats: OS = ([2*B + IV + (EV/4)]*[L/100] + 5)*Nm]

where

- HP = your Pokemon's real HP;
- OtherStat = real value for stat besides HP;
- Base = [base stat for the species](https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all);
- IV = individual values;
- EV = effort values;
- Nature = nature modifier {1, 1.1, 0.9}

Note there's a fair bit of rounding down (the L-shaped brackets), so you will likely get small rounding errors using these formulas backwards:

### Using algebra, we can solve for IV + EV/4:

IV + (EV/4) = x = (HP - Level - 10) * (100/Level) - 2*Base

IV + (EV/4) = x = (OtherStat/Nature - 5) * (100/Level) - 2*Base

That tells you how your pokemon differs from a default (wild) one of the same species, nature, and level. After calculating x, solving each equation for EV with IV at 0 and 31 gives you the possible range for EV values. If you know your IV within a better range, you can determine your EVs more closely too.
You can also use this equation to figure out the IVs of a Pokemon you just caught, solving for x when you know EV to be 0.

Answer (score 4):

The traditional way to calculate EV is to use the EV reducing berries.

```
Pomeg      - reduces HP EV
Kelpsy     - reduces Atk EV
Qualot     - reduces Def EV
Hondew     - reduces SpA EV
Grepa      - reduces SpD EV
Tamato     - reduces Spd EV
```

Each of these berries typically reduces the number of EV on a particular stat by 10, the exception is in Gen IV, where the berries would drop the EVs to 100 if the EVs were above that.

So, if your Pokemon had 252 Atk EVs, you would need 26 uses of Kelpsy to make it zero, and you will get a message along the lines of:

> Eevee became more friendly! Its base Atk can't go lower!

when the EVs hit 0. You will need the same number of berries for an EV of 251, and you would need 25 berries for a total EV of 250.

*Unless you are in Gen IV where you would need 11 berries in **both** cases. It is actually not easy to calculate the EVs accurately in Gen IV.*

From that, you can get an idea of what your EVs are, to the nearest 10 points for all except Gen IV. If you want to get even more precise of a number, you will have to give some EVs and try again.

E.g.

Your current Pokemon has 164 EVs in HP (but you don't know that yet). Save your game and give the Pokemon Pomeg berries and you observe that you used 17 berries to drop it down to 0. Restore your previous save game and battle 1 Pokemon to increase the EVs (Caterpie, Wooper, Gulpin, Bidoof all give 1 HP EV each) and check the EVs again.

After battling 1 of these, you should be requiring 17 berries still because the total EV would then be 165.

However, couple of tries later, you find that after battling 7 of them, you require 18 berries to drop the attack to 0, so you know that the EV is 171-7 = 164 for HP.

Note that if you are in Gen V, then you can use Wings instead to add the EVs more easily.

I didn't really use a source, but I learnt those through [serebii](http://www.serebii.net/games/evs.shtml) way back and their article is pretty detailed, so explore to your trainer's heart's content.

---

In Gen VI, it is easier and you can use the Reset Bag the way @SentinelGaming described, that is save your game, use the reset bag, note down the figures that appear when the bag is used before they disappear and restore your previous save game. If you can read the numbers easily, you can press the Home button when the numbers pop up so you 'freeze' the image and can take your time to note them down.

---

If I take for example a Charizard of Lv 100 in FireRed. I want to know the EVs in Special Attack. I don't know its IVs nor EVs in Special Attack. Let's say the EVs are actually 198, but I don't know this yet.

**I save the game.**

When I use a Hondew berry, I find that I need **20** berries until the berry doesn't have any effect. That immediately tells me the Charizard must have **between 191 to 200** EVs in Special Attack, because:
200 EVs will require 20 berries
199 EVs will require 20 berries (19 berries remove 190 EVs and the last removes 9 EVs)
...
191 EVs will require 20 berries (19 berries remove 190 EVs and the last removes 1 EV)

I restore the save game and use a couple of other berries to reduce **other** stats, in case the Charizard has maxed out of EVs. I give the Charizard one more EV in Special Attack by attacking a Pokemon which gives 1 SpA EV, e.g. Oddish, and do the same as before with the berries. It takes 20 berries again, so the possibilities narrow down to **191-199** EVs in SpA.

I repeat with one more EV in SpA until the number of berries change. The number of berries change when I need 21 berries until the berry stops having any effects; i.e. after I added 3 EVs to SpA.

That means the number of EVs + 3 gave me a number that is one more than a number divisible by 10. That means that Original EVs + 3 EVs = 201 EVs.

From there you see that the EV must be 198.

Calculating from the stats can yield numbers induced with errors from the game rounding numbers and the unknown value of IV.

Comment: Use the traditional way for games other than Gen 6 but as long as they are Gen 3 onwards, i.e. including Pokemon Fire Red.

Answer (score -1):

From my research, this is how EV's effect your Pokemon

To start, 4 EVs = +1 stat. After this every 8 EVs = +1 stat.

There are however three numbers that do not follow this trend.  36, 116, and 196.  These three numbers grant +2 stat upon reaching.  So, 4 = 1, 12 = 2, 20 = 3, 28 = 4, but 36 = 6.

(I've dubbed the EVs 4, 36, 116, and 196 jump values, because they jump over the usual 8=1 pattern)

Comment: ...so how do you calculate EVs with this knowledge?